# Setting up the trap

Tags: word, knowledge, wordplay, language

> Start with eleven in one e four e six;
>   add what is missing from otherhood, oke, icks;
>   improving position, go upwards by one;
>   mix up for organs, remove fifty-one.
>
> Add to the end an American nation;
>   abbreviate all and add short operation;
>   age for a few more years, then turn around;
>   prefix by fifteen – a trap on the ground!

What have we caught in our trap?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Start with eleven in one e four e six;

> **onze** - eleven in French, and in chess 1. e4 e6 is the French defence.

add what is missing from otherhood, oke, icks;

> **bronze** - br is missing from brotherhood, broke, bricks (credit Omega Krypton).

improving position, go upwards by one;

> **silver** - one position above bronze.

mix up for organs, remove fifty-one.

> **vers** - livers (mix silver) minus li (credit Omega Krypton).

Add to the end an American nation;

> **versus** - appending the United States.

abbreviate all and add short operation;

> **VSOP** - Vs as an abbrev. for versus and add op for operation.

age for a few more years, then turn around;

> **ox** -  VSOP brandy is at least 4 yrs old, XO (Extra Old) is more than six years then reverse.

prefix by fifteen – a trap on the ground!

> **fox** as F is fifteen in hexadecimal.

Comment: nice job... impressive! +1

Comment: Oops, didn't realize the letter e is written with one e and not like bee cee dee etc. Fixed now!

Answer (score 5):

Very Partial answer... Only solving part of a stanza...

`Start with eleven in one ee four ee six;`

> **XI**, one = I, four = IV, six = VI ...?

`add what is missing from otherhood, oke, icks;`

> **BR**, as in BRotherhood, BRoke, BRicks

`improving position, go upwards by one;`

> rot25 or rot1...

`remove fifty-one`

> Remove **LI**...